# What kinds of music you don't like? or What kinds of music don't you like?

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, grammaticality, wh-questions

What is more proper to say:

> What kinds of music you don't like?
>    What kinds of music don't you like?

Can you please explain why?

Answer (score 1):

"**What kinds of music don't you like?**" is the correct one.

A simpler way to understand this is, consider "do" in place of "don't".

The sentences are:

```
"What kinds of music you do like?"
"What kinds of music do you like?"
```

The second one is correct, right?

It's the same way for your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can say "What kinds of music don't you like?"   But I would usually phrase it as

> What kinds of music do you not like? / or What kinds of music do you dislike.

The sentence "What kinds of music don't you like?" sounds like a rhetorical question suggesting "You seem to like all kinds of music!"  And not expecting an answer.

As there is a good word "dislike", I'd use that instead.